# Why all my elements at the array be the last added value in this C program?

Tags: c

I want to create an array which elements look like this "1A 2A 3A... etc". My problem that every time, the program set all of the elements the value of the last added value. So my final output is "25F 25F 25F..."

Here is my code:

```
void func() {
    char c[10];
    char s[10];
    char *arr[150];
    int idx = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 25; ++i) {
        for (char j = 'A'; j <= 'F'; ++j) {
            sprintf(c, "%d%c", i,j);
            strcpy(s,c);
            arr[idx++] = s;
            printf("%s", s);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 150; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: each element of arr is a pointer to the same string s

Comment: But s is redefined every running of the loops.

Comment: @GáborKiss No it isn't, It's modifed, but there is **only one** `s`.

Comment: use strdup in the loop to make different copies

Answer (score 1):

here

```
            arr[idx++] = s;
```

you make all pointers in the array to point to the array `s`, so all of them point to the same place and so they all show as the same value in the output.

Something like:

```
            arr[idx++] = strdup(s);
```

should make you a copy of the string stored in `s` at the time you `sprintf()` it, and having a dynamically allocated array (you will need to call `free(arr[idx++]);` in another loop later, when you are finished with all these allocations)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `arr` is an array of pointers and all the pointers point to the **same** place `s`. So when you change `s` it seems like all the elements of `arr` are updated.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea for the solution?

Comment: @GáborKiss I'm tempted to say switch to C++ and use `std::string` instead of pointers. But maybe that is not an option for you.

Comment: @GáborKiss If you want an array of ten pointers and you want them all to point at different strings, then there is no choice but to have ten different strings.